# Foreach skipping, joomla framework in using

Tags: php, joomla, foreach

I have in using joomla, have a input field and must add on result page of com_search a additional query, if i run this query in a sql editor i get 2 results, but in joomla is my *foreach* every time skipping.

If i do *$db->getPrefix();* i see table prefix, so i thing to $db and $query are true.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('#__k2_categories');
$query->where("`name` LIKE '%MY_SEARCH_WORD%'");
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach($results as $entry) :

echo $results->name . "<br />";

endforeach;
```

Comment: It should be `$entry->name`, shouldn't it?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaa sorry and thanke you, have 2 hours searched for solution :(